# Displaying a list of pivot tables with their parameters

Tags: excel, analytics, pivot-table, vba

I have a workbook with many worksheets with many pivot tables. **Having an overview in one place of all these pivot tables** would be great to ensure I have consistent parameters, titles, etc.

It should display key info such as:

Worksheet name, Pivot Table Name, Pivot Table location, Hyperlink to location, chose parameters (such as OLAP support, current connected slicers, etc., Type (power pivot or standard)

I guess we would all be happy to have this for all our complex applications.
Would anyone have a clue on how to design this in VBA or something else?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out where to start. I have now over 50 pivots in this file and somehow one of them turns the OLAP function on and my slicers don't work properly anymore. I'd love to have this list somewhere so I could easily locate the pivot with the faulty parameter. I am sure I am not the only one with this issue, has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to loop through pivot tables and grab information with something like:

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet
For Each pvt In ws.PivotTables

'collect data about pivot tables and output somewhere..
Next pvt
```

if the pivot tables are in multiple worksheets then nest that loop inside a loop that cycles through the workbooks worksheets.

Does that provide an adequate starting point for you?